# strpos - not giving expected results

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, strpos

I am trying to run through some info from my database to check if the itemcode is included as one of the items 'keys'.

I was expecting this code to show me only the rows where the code IS NOT a key - however I seem to get a  mixture of results (some where the code is there and others where it isn't)

I have tried changing true to false and I get a similar set of results.

```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        $itemcode = $row['itemcode'];
        $keys = $row['keys'];

        if (strpos($metakeywords, $itemcode) !== true) {
        echo 'code: ' . $itemcode . " keys: " . $metakeywords . "<br /><br />" ;
    }
```

**Expected output:**
code: ABC123 keys: planter, green, window
code: DEF456 keys: blue, outdoors, garden

**Actual Output:** 
code: ABC123 keys: planter, green, window
code: CBA321 keys: red, indoors, planter, CBA321 
code: DEF456 keys: blue, outdoors, garden
code: FED654 keys: pink, plant, FED654, self-watering

Can anyone help?

Comment: You want to check `=== FALSE` instead of `!== TRUE`.  `strpos` returns either a number or FALSE.  Neither of those are ever TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strpos()` doesn't return `true` when it finds a match, it returns the position of the match.

If you want to know when there's no match, use:

```
if (strpos($metakeywords, $itemcode) === false) {
```

You could probably do this entirely in the SQL query, rather than in PHP, though.

Answer (score 1):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) cannot ever return true. It returns a number if there is a match, and false otherwise. Since you want the if statement block to run when there is not a match, change `true` to `false` *and* `!==` to `===`:

```
if ( strpos($metakeywords, $itemcode) === false ) {
```